# Windows Phone 7 - OutOfMemory Exception in emulator but not on device

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, emulation, device, out-of-memory

At the point in my app where I load a lot of textures, I get an **OutOfMemory Exception** when I debug on the emulator but on the device, it works!

This is a big problem for me because I share a device with another developer and now that we have this problem, we can't both test at our own time with the emulator when the other is using the device.

Anyone know what could be the problem?

(its a game I'm working on in **XNA** by the way)

Comment: You've not provided much information which could help privide an answer: What device(s)? How many textures? How can this be reproduced? Does it only happen in debug? How much memory is actually being used?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the new emulator from the Beta Mango SDK - that's it. We've had memory leaks, crashes, etc. You can attach a piece of code that shows the memory usage -> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/12/16/monitoring-memory-usage-on-windows-phone-7.aspx it's for silverlight, but with a bit of work you can convert it to xna.